# Can I display a custom field inside a Loop Query block?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-shortcode

I’m fairly new to Wordpress and I’m trying all my best to learn, but I can’t find a solution for this one…
I’ve been using the Twenty Twenty-Two theme and I’ve added a custom field ("*city*") to my articles.
Of course when I add a Query Loop block on my homepage, the visual editor allows me to use Titles, Categories and so on… but it won’t let me use my custom field.

I tried adding what follows to *functions.php*:

```
add_shortcode( 'city', 'return_my_custom_value' );
function return_my_custom_value() {
    $myCity = do_shortcode(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'city', true));
    return $myCity;
}
```

But it won’t work, because then I use the following shortcode inside my Query Loop block:

```
[city]
```

and it shows a list of my articles all with the same '*city*' value, repeated — which is the one I assigned to the page I’m showing the query on (my homepage).

Any solution for this? I would really appreciate each suggestion. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Hi @HowardE, thank you for your comment. I did, but the result is still the same… I'm still getting the same value over and over.

Answer (score 0):

We have checked the code you are not calling shortcode inside the query loop. we have updated the code you can use the code. Please check below the updated code and add in the functions.php file.

```
add_shortcode( 'city', 'return_my_custom_value' );
function return_my_custom_value() {
   $myCity = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'city', true);
   return $myCity;
}
```

Please use the following shortcode inside your query loop block

```
echo do_shortcode('[city]');
```